# css/js file path update in the html file using grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I have a folder structure, when I create the build folder using grunt, a hash need to be prefixed with .css file and that name need to be updated in the link tag in index.php.

```
sitename/css/main.css    
sitename/index.php
```

After executing grunt command build folder need to be created with following structure

```
build/sitename/css/2ed6bccd.main.css
build/sitename/index.php
```

In the index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

need to be replaced with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="2ed6bccd.main.css">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either [grunt-rev](https://github.com/cbas/grunt-rev) or [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) tasks together with [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) for cache busting of static files in your index.php

example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
config: {
  app: 'sitename',
  dist: 'build/sitename'
},
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
      ]
    }]
  }
},
rev: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      src: [
        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
      ]
    }
  }
},
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= config.app %>/index.php',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
  }
},
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.php'],
  css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/*.js',
  options: {
    dirs: [
      '<%= config.dist %>', 
      '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
    ]      
  }
},
htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
      src: [
        '{,*/}*.php',
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        'bower_components/**/*',
        'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
        'fonts/*',
        'data/*'
      ]
    }, {
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/images',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images',
      src: [
        'generated/*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
}});
```

Your grunt build task:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
     'clean:dist',
     'useminPrepare',
     'concat:generated',
     'cssmin:generated',
     //'uglify:generated',
     'copy:dist',
     'rev',
     'usemin'
  ]);
```

And then in your `index.php`, put your `css` ref in the following block

```
  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

This will rename `sitename/css/main.css` with an 8 character long hash prefix. For example `sitename/css/9becff3a.main.css`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I'm really sorry I could not respond on time. I just tried your code but, it didn't gave me the expected result. 1) 'build' folder is not created. 2) it overwrite the main.css to sitename/css/9becff3a.main.css as it should happen in the build folder. 3) in the main.php it didn't update the new file name of .css file.

Comment: I have a question about my approach also. In my site I'm using so many library files also. When I create the 'build', only the modified files I need to copy or whole site I need to copy to the build folder? How can I  handle the revert, if the something break in the production server? If I copy only modified files in the build, there will be main .css files in the production, how can I avoid these? What is the best approach for it?

Comment: 1- You will need to `copy` all files to the build folder every time you deploy. before copying all the resources, `clean:dist` you destination folder. 2-you don't revert from prod, cause you should deploy to a test/stage environment that mimic you prod before you deploy. take a look at the gruntfile in this example https://gist.github.com/doomsbuster/7507710. Notice the diff between build tasks and the default ones.

Comment: I've edited the solution to include a copy task that will copy you php to build. Unfortunately, I can't see your gruntfile. good luck

Comment: All the issues I mentioned still exists. grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'rev', 'usemin']); this is my registerTask() function call. is this correct? as I mentioned in the previous comment the issues are 1) 'build' folder is not created. 2) it overwrite the main.css to sitename/css/9becff3a.main.css as it should happen in the build folder. 3) in the main.php it didn't update the new file name of .css file.

Comment: Here I have attached the Gruntfile.js based on your link. it is not creating the build folder. http://jsfiddle.net/Saneesh/0vahf1m4/1/

Comment: @Sun, The solution has been updated and tested. You had a couple of issues in your code. The main.css should be w/in a folder called `styles` instead of `css`. feel free to rename it, but don't forget to update gruntfile.js if you do so. You were not copying the html/php like I mentioned. but most importantly, you were missing the css block in you index.php. refer the `usemin` documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much! at last its started to work!. some more issues I'm seeing. They are, in my styles folder there are many files like foo.css,bar.css, main.css, bootsrap.min.css. What I want is, mearge foo.css, bar.css and main.css to main.css. then copy the bootstrap.css as it is. Similarly in scripts folder have script.js and foo.js. these two files mearge and create script.js and this file should use for uglify. jquery.js and modernizr-transitions.js should copy as it is.

Comment: @Richid, When I try to update the structure for my exact need its not working, so I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389559/grunt-build-folder-structure-for-drupal